# specify default schema for a database in db2 client

Tags: unix, db2, database-schema, aix, catalog

Do we have any way to specify default schema in cataloged DBs in db2 client in AIX.

The problem is , when it's connecting to DB, it's taking user ID as default schema and that's where it's failing.

We have too many scripts that are doing transactions to DB without specifying schema in their db2 sql statements. So it's not feasible to change scripts at all.

Also we can't create users to match schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create alias in the new user schema that points to the tables with the other schema. Refer these links :

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000910.html

http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/181247-do-you-have-always-specify-schema-when-using-db2-clp

Answer (score 4):

You can try to type `SET SCHEMA=<your schema> ;` before executing your queries.

Comment: Connections are made in script themselves. We can't do that

Comment: You put this line right after the connection. OR you connect with the user that has the same name as the schema. It is not an AIX problem, it is the default DB2 behaviour.

Comment: This was useful for me. I had to switch connections to HTTP on a DB2 Warehouse instance. My hundreds of queries needed updated - or I could send `SET SCHEMA` before each using `/sql_jobs` endpoint (IBM's DB2 Warhouse in Cloud doesn't allow making your own endpoints - or stored procedures, so this was the best I could do with that very limited "service".
So, in my query options, for `command`, I had `SET SCHEMA MY_SCHEMA; SOME EXISTING QUERY` with `separator: ';'`. Disappointing I couldn't just set it once - it needs set every POST...

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Not sure if this work (I am without a DB2 database at the moment, but it seems that work) and depending on your DB2 version.

You can create a stored procedure that just changes the current schema and then set the SP as connect proc. You can test some conditions before make that schema change, for example if the stored procedure is executed from the AIX server directly with a given user.

You configure the database to use this SP each time a connection is established by modifying connect_proc

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0057371.html
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0057372.html